# get email attatchment for POP 3 received as winmail.dat

Tags: jakarta-mail, pop3, winmail.dat

When I try to get attatchment from POP 3 mail, I am getting them as winmail.dat, not the original attached file name. How can I get the original file name?

```
for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) 
        {
            BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);

            if(!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition())) 
            {
                //do something
            }
            else
            {
                bodyPart.getFileName(); // here only get the winmail.dat
            }   
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the Exchange Settings, and sadly you going to need to extract the original contents from the WinMail.dat using [JTNEF](http://www.freeutils.net/source/jtnef/).

*"The Java TNEF package is an open source code implementation of a TNEF message handler, which can be used as a command-line utility or integrated into Java-based mail applications to extract the original message content."*

This is found on the JavaMail's third party tools.

As alternative and what looks simpler is [POI-HMEF](http://poi.apache.org/hmef/index.html)

Sample extraction:

```
public void extract(String winmailFilename, String directoryName) throws Exception {
   HMEFContentsExtractor ext = new HMEFContentsExtractor(new File(winmailFilename));

   File dir = new File(directoryName);
   File rtf = new File(dir, "message.rtf");
   if(! dir.exists()) {
       throw new FileNotFoundException("Output directory " + dir.getName() + " not found");
   }

   System.out.println("Extracting...");
   ext.extractMessageBody(rtf);
   ext.extractAttachments(dir);
   System.out.println("Extraction completed");
}
```

There is also a sample for printing the contents [here](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/scratchpad/src/org/apache/poi/hmef/dev/HMEFDumper.java).

Comment: just one question. Does all the exchange mail services return like WinMail.dat for the attachment ?

Comment: It does appear to be Microsoft's preferred way. It appears to be used by Outlook and Exchange 2000-2010 AFAIK. But this format can be changed on Exchange Server itself.

Comment: I used JTNEF and modified according to my requirements. Thanks for the input.